# How to Index/Match to Pull Data from dependent Array

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

[image: Example Image, Open This First]

I would like to know how to use a combination of Index/Match to pull data from one column to another by referencing multiple criteria. From the image attached, Column R should be auto populated (with a formula) with values from column A based on its corresponding reference in Column S.

Column S will match with Row 1 to find its column location in the array B2:K11. In the matched column, excel should then find the Row number that contains any value equal to or greater than 0 (or not blank).  When it finds the row with a value it will pull the value from column A into Column R.

For example, in R2, it will look at S2 and see it needs the location for X1. It will go to the array and find X1 in B1. It will go down the column and find a value in B3 since the "10" is there. It will pull A3 into R2.

Im trying to do this without using VBA and as clean and efficiently as possible (i.e if possible without helper columns, and less processing power required). I have provided an example image of what I am trying to accomplish as I am unable to upload the actual file.

I have tried a variety of Index/Match combinations but have been unable to modify the array not to be fixed to a specific column. I have also tried ADDRESS() to create a custom array but this did not work, Attempted formulas are shown below:

In R2 to find column location: =MATCH(S2,A1:K1)

To Find Row number in B2:B11 (single column):

```
{=MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(B2:B11),0} 
{=MATCH(TRUE,B2:B11>=0,0)} 
=MATCH((LOOKUP(2,1/(B$2:B$11<>""),B$2:B$11)),B$2:B$11,0)
```

I need to combine these, but the array of the column to look in should be addressed to the column which was matched.

To Index column A:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,ROW,0)
```

Overall:

```
=INDEX(A:A,(=MATCH((LOOKUP(2,1/(COLUMN NUMBER MATCHED<>""),COLUMN NUMBER MATCHED)),COLUMN NUMBER MATCHED,0)),0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values in your Array are all numeric, you can use:

```
R2:  =LOOKUP(9.9+307,INDEX($B:$K,0,MATCH(S2,$B$1:$K$1,0)),$A:$A)
```

If the values might be numeric or alpha, then try:

```
R2:  =LOOKUP(2,1/LEN(INDEX($B:$K,0,MATCH(S2,$B$1:$K$1,0))),$A:$A)
```

In each case, the formula will match the last entry in the particular `X` labelled column.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! This is exactly what I was looking for.